# XSD DateTime validation on value with no separators

Tags: xml, datetime, xsd

I'm working on a XSD schema to validate a XML file filled with data which a client is exporting from their system.

The way they export dates/datetimes from the system is by outputting them without any separators, e.g. 20150323151728 (format: YYYYMMDDhhmmss)

Does there exist a way I can input that format in my schema to make the XML pass the validation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Among the possible solutions are these three.

## Reformat before validation

A perhaps simpler approach is to insert a SAX filter between the data source and the validator which looks for the date-time values and reformats them according to ISO 8601 rules so they can be validated against xsd:dateTime.  (Watch out for leap seconds.)

In his answer, Michael Kay calls this *tranform-before-validating*; he is right that it's a useful design pattern.

## Cleaner export

Depending on the client, it may also be worth suggesting that when exporting to XML, they export the date-time stamps in ISO 8601 format.  This is either simple or trivially simple on a technical level; on a political or organizational level, of course, it is either simple or absolutely impossible.  You are presumably in a better position to judge how practical this is than any reader of Stack Overflow; if you don't already know the answer, asking the question may prove informative (but may also prove dangerous, so it doesn't say here that you *should* ask).

## Regex for date-times

It's possible to describe the set of Gregorian dates (and similarly the set of Gregorian date-times) with a regular expression, though the regular expression tends to be rather cumbersome and derivation by hand is error-prone.  It's easier if you can use Boolean operators (in particular negation):  the set of legal dates is (a) the set of all dates where the day of the month is 1 to 30, plus (b) the set of all dates where the month is 1 or 3 or 5 or 7 or 8 or 10 or 12 and the day of the month is 31, minus (c) the set of all dates where the month is 2 and the day of the month is 29 or 30, plus (d) the set of all dates where the year is a leap year but not evenly divisible by 100, the month is 2, and the day is 29.

In XSD 1.1, conditional type assignment can be used to get the effect of Boolean negation, though the first-wins type assignment rules will force you to put the negative conditions first (if the literal matches the patterns $bogus-february-29 or $other-bogus-february, then bind the element to xsd:error, else ...).

## Postscript

Actually, it turns out to be simple enough to do this even without negation.  For clarity, I'll factor the time and year portions of the pattern out into general entities, declared as

```
<!ENTITY hh "([01][0-9]|2[0-3])">
<!ENTITY mm "([05][0-9])">
<!ENTITY ss "([05][0-9])">
<!ENTITY midnight "240000">

<!ENTITY tod "(&hh;&mm;&ss;|&midnight;)">

<!ENTITY yyyy "(([1-9][0-9]*)?[0-9]{4})">
<!ENTITY leapyear "([1-9][0-9]*)?[0-9]{2}(0[48]|[2468][048]|[13579][26])">
```

Now the type you want is something like this:

```
<simpleType name="YYYYMMDDhhmmss">
  <annotation>
    <documentation>
      <p xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
        A date-time stamp in the form YYYYMMDDhhmmss.
      </      
    </
  </

  <restriction base="string">
    <pattern value="&yyyy;(0[0-9]|1[0-2])(0[1-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-8])&tod;">
      <annotation>
        <documentation>Days 01-28 of any month.</
      </
    </
    <pattern value="&yyyy;(0[469]|11)(29|30)&tod;">
      <annotation>
        <documentation>29-30 of April, June, September, November.</
      </
    </
    <pattern value="&yyyy;(0[13578]|1[02])(29|30|31)">
      <annotation>
        <documentation>29-31 of January, March, May, July, 
          August, October, December.</documentation>
      </annotation>
    </pattern>
    <pattern value="&leapyear;0229&tod;">
      <annotation>
        <documentation>29 February.</
      </
    </
  </
</
```

Answer (score 0):

One option that is often overlooked is the transform-before-validating design pattern: rather than validating the XML as it arrives, transform it to something "cleaner" before validating. In this case, "cleaner" means something that uses ISO dates/times in the format that XSD expects.